# Access multiple values by index in a view

Tags: views, entities

I have a multi-value field. When I output this field in a view I use `Rewrite results` and reference this field as `[field_product_image]`. This outputs all the images of the field.

How could I output only certain element of this array, e.g. second image **using rewrite results** (this is essential)?
Neither of these works:

`[field_product_image:0]`, `[field_product_image_0]`, `[field_product_image-0]`

Comment: are you using drupal 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to check the **Group multiple values** and then set to show **1** values  and set starting from **1**. see the below screenshot for clarification

> [image]

if you check the rewrite output of this filed you can see the token for that filed, for your case it would probably

> **[field_product_image_1]**

So if you want to retrieve the image separately from the array, you have to do the above steps for each image, for example if you want the 3rd image, then you have to set starting from **2** and its tokes is `[field_product_image_2]`, if you want 4th image, then you have to set starting from **3** and its token is `[field_product_image_3]`.

Below screenshots will help you to understand easily.

I added each filed separately to retrieve each image

> [image]

and its tokens and above method is for Drupal 6, you can do it in the same way for D7.

> [image]

Comment: I think this is way more complicated than my answer. Prove me wrong. I'm trying to understand this. First of all, where do you find Group multiple values checkbox?

Comment: @KariKääriäinen seriously have you never seen this before ? i took screen shot from views

Comment: But how do you get into this dialog? I'm assuming we are talking about D7?

Comment: @KariKääriäinen It is D6 :)

Comment: Why? I can see you asked OP that but he never answered.

Comment: @KariKääriäinen that's why I decided to answer for D6 and I don't have D7 vanila at the moment. but of course both of them have little difference.

Comment: Could you add the version info and how to get into that dialog?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13017/discussion-between-bala-and-kari-kaariainen)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a template specific for this view field, so you can access all your variables with PHP, which is way more convenient to do such things.

So if your field id is "field_product_image", then you should find and download views-view-field.tpl.php, rename it "views-view-field--field-product-image.tpl.php", put your code inside and upload it to your theme/template folder.

You can see in your view, under "Advanced" > "Theme" what is the name to override default views field template and if the overriding template is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed in this question that defining **which** values to output and **how** to output them would have to happen in the same place, Rewrite results. However, there is nice support for separating these in (D7) Views Configure Field dialog: Multiple field settings for "what" and Rewrite results for "how".

So for D7 use "Multiple field settings". For example "Display 1 starting from 1" outputs the second image. Now you can access your image in "Rewrite results" simply using [field_product_image].

In D6 these settings are in the same dialog, but they work the same way, I believe.

Comment: I need to use Rewrite results. I write some code there using image[1].

Comment: Oh OK. Rewriting seems to happen after Multiple field settings so you CAN use it. So in Multiple field settings figure out which images to output, and in Rewrite results figure out how to display them.

Comment: Well, my question is exactly "to figure out how to display them".

Comment: You can display them anyway you want using normal methods like "Image style" in the "Field configuration", theming etc. I thought your original question was about how to only display one certain image instead of all images in a multi-value field. Are you asking now about how to for example style the image or have I completely missed something?

Comment: Or are you wondering what token to use in Rewrite results? It's just the field name, [field_product_image] so no ":0" or "_0" or "-0" or anything like that is needed. I updated my answer.