# How to get different size image on views

Tags: views, 6, media

I have a view that fetches content that is then shown in a block. It shows 16 nodes and each node has title, date and image. The images are set to use the imagecache preset in the view field settings.

I need to show the first and the seventh image with different sizes, 750x400 instead of 300x300.

Is it possible to achieve this changing the view settings or on template level?

Comment: Why not just use different views for the 1st and 7th?

Comment: But then I would need to use 4 different views, right? One for the first, second for 2-6, third for 7 and fourth views for rest? Not sure how could I achieve this with separate views.

Comment: If you build your page with panels, you can reuse your views and pass arguments so you've got two kind of views and invoke them several times. Another option is to do all this in the theming layer and invoke the imagecache settings programatically

Comment: Use Group multiple values option - for details http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102019/access-multiple-values-by-index-in-a-view and for your case create separate field for 1st and 7th field, set image style and for 2 to 6 create another field with default image style.

Answer (score 0):

I used IMCE under Drupal 6.x. However, the resize only occurs at the time you upload and image with their editor which is cumbersome, to say the least. It depends on who has to upload the images, I guess.

Otherwise, CSS, as others mentioned, is probably your best bet. Now a day, browsers properly (cleanly) resize images so they still look good. (10 years ago, however, it was horrible!)

If you want to use IMCE and need to resize existing images, you could look into using `convert` on your server to resize existing files. However, you'll have to write an intelligent script that properly renames everything properly...